# Getting NUnit tests to run on Visual Studio Team Services (Mac Build agent)

Tags: macos, visual-studio, msbuild, nunit, azure-devops

I can't seem to get NUnit tests to run on our Mac build agent using VSTS

Here are the build steps I am using in VSTS:

[image]

Note, Test assemblies is disabled because the Mac build agent does not have VSTest.exe. In the options menu, there is no way to completely remove the need for VSTest so I cannot use that step on the mac build agent.

Is there a way to run NUnit tests in the MSBuild step?

Things I have tried:

- Install NUnit test adapter in Visual Studio
- Install MSBuildTasks + Nunit MSBuild task (Not sure how to use it)

As a last resort, I can add a shell script to run nunit-console on the mac build agent, but I would prefer to avoid that. The reason the build agent needs mac os x is because we're building an iOS and Android app with Xamarin.

Screenshot of the references and NuGet packages in VS:

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dGm2.png)

Build output:

[image]

Test assemblies are created, but I can't get them to run

Answer (score 1):

The instruction for how to use MSBuild tasks for NUnit can be found here: [NUnit3](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Documentation/TaskDocs.md#NUnit3) or [NUnit](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Documentation/TaskDocs.md#NUnit). You need to update your project file to import the tasks according to this: [Get Started](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks#getting-started) and then add the NUnit MSBuild tasks into your project file. And you can also add an [Exec Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) in your project file to call NUnit console to run the NUnit test.

Comment: The second point is actually incorrect. You cannot run a Xamarin.iOS Automated build using a Windows machine. Even if, that machine is also connected to a mac. To automate a Xamarin.iOS build you must you a mac running a valid build agent

Comment: @user1 Yes, you are right. Thanks for remind that. I have removed that section. :)